# Shouldn't declaration match its definition when array is involved?

Tags: c++, arrays

There are two source files in my program.

An array is defined in **A.cpp**.

```
// compiler: MSVC2005 SP2    
// A.cpp

// defines an array of type "int [100]"
int a[100] = {3};
```

It is used in **B.cpp**.

```
// B.cpp

// declares an array of type "int []"
extern int a[];

int main()
{
  // prints 3 correctly
  cout << a[0] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

AFAIK, linker will raise an error if it cannot find any matched definition for a declaration if the declared identifier is used. Here, **int []** and **int [100]** are two different types, obviously.

**Why, in this case, isn't there any link error?** Is it guaranteed by *the Standard* that array size is trivial during matching of declaration/definition? Or it's just implementation-specific? A quote from *the Standard* will be appreciated if any.

**Edit:**  iammilind mentioned in his answer that linker can run correctly(his compiler is gcc) **even if the type does NOT match between declaration and definition**. Is it REQUIRED by the Standard or just a way of gcc? I guess this is a far more important issue to figure out.

Comment: The error is in the "obviously".

Comment: @Alf. Nope. Quote from the Standard 8.3.4 "The type
“derived-declarator-type-list array of N T” is a different type from the type “derived-declarator-type-list
array of unknown bound of T,”

Comment: @Erik: thanks for the quote. Rather than get into a discussion about what that "obviously" entailed, which of course you know best!, I suggest that you select AndreyT's answer as solution, even though in my view his use of the word "match" is a bit misleading. Anyway, the reason that you can get things to link where the types don't conform to the language rules for matching, is that compilers do not go to a lot of effort to catch errors here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both C and C++ a declaration of an object `a` of incomplete type will match the definition of object `a` where the type is complete. What you observe simply illustrates the fact that in C++ you are allowed to use incomplete types in non-defining declarations. But once you get to the definition the type must be complete.

This behavior is not restricted to arrays. For example, you can declare

```
extern class X x;
```

for a totally unknown class `X`, and then, when `class X` is already fully defined, you can define

```
X x;
```

which will match to the above declaration.

The same thing happens with your array. Firstly you declare an object of incomplete type

```
extern int a[];
```

and then you define it with complete type

```
int a[100];
```

The types here indeed are not matching. However, the C++ language never required them to match. For example, 3.9/7 explicitly states

> The declared type of an array object might be an array of unknown size
>   and therefore be incomplete at one point in a translation unit and
>   complete later on; the array types at those two points (“array of
>   unknown bound of T” and “array of N T”) are different types.

It means that *the same* array object can have incomplete type initially, but acquire a complete type later on. (See also the example in 3.9/7). This doesn't, of course, mean that you can declare `a` as an `int` and then define it as a `double`. The only type-related freedom you have here is, again, to complete an incomplete type. No more.

Comment: That makes sense for the "incomplete type". But why it still links if I declare "extern int a[50]"? "int [50]" is a complete, different type(than int [100]).

Comment: @Eric, Now, that's because of mangling, ideally this should not compile, but your compiler doesn't include the dimension in mangled name.

Comment: @unkulunkulu, ok, so does Standard requires that declaration should match definition if both are complete types?

Answer (score 1):

First of all that code should not give any error. The specification `int a[]` is different from `a[100]` but is compatible with it (it's just incomplete).

A second important point is that you cannot count on C++ compiler/linker giving errors for cross-module incoherence. For example in a C++ program you cannot have the same class defined twice with a different definition, but the compiler is not REQUIRED to tell you about this problem, it's a burden left on the programmers.

If an implementation detects and signals this kind of problem then fine, but an implementation not telling anything about them and just creating crashing executables is still perfectly compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Here it says that "C++ allows the possibility of leaving the square brackets empty [ ]. In this case, the compiler will assume a size for the array that matches the number of values included between braces { }". So if this ref is right, it seems to be part of the standard.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: @Laurent, what you mean is an array definition int a[] = {3} and what I'm asking is a non-defining declaration extern int a[];

Answer (score 0):

Your question is genuine. Here there are few problems.

When you declare two symbols with same names; then there is no check
    from linker for its type/size etc. It just resolves them and
    correlate them together. For example try declaring `extern float
    a[];` or `extern int a[3];` it will still work. This is the way C++
    linker is (unfortunately) designed.

So the solution is to declare them in header file and `#include` in both of a.cpp and b.cpp.

Comment: Are you sure declaring a different-type-but-same-name variable can pass the linking? It's NOT the case, at least in MSVC.

Comment: @Eric: i tried `extern int* a` `extern double* a`, `extern char* a` and similar to what @Marcelo Cantos mentioned, i also tried `extern int ( *a)(int, char*)`, all of them passed the linking. But not in MSVC. I am using gcc-4.5. But yes i removed the `cout` statement.

Comment: @Eric, In gcc it passes; the linker matches 2 independent variables with same name in different translation units. So it's better to `extern` it in a header file and `#include` it in whatever `.cpp`.

Comment: @Aditya, no... You cannot remove the statement using the variable. Otherwise, the compiler is smart enough to optimize away your declaration if possible. Try use that variable.

Comment: @iammilind, have you tried using that variable in gcc, or just declare without using them like what Aditya did?

Comment: @Eric, I have tried it; if you use `exteren float a[];`; it prints something like `4.2039e-45`. Also may be MSVC linker is capable enough to catch `float/int` difference and gcc is not. But why should one take a chance ? It's very trivial to declare `extern`s in a header file.

Comment: @Eric: Only while declaring `extern int ( *a)(int, char*)` I removed `cout` otherwise the didn't compile. For other tests of ` extern int* a extern double* a and extern char* a` I used `cout`, and there was no linker error.

Answer (score 0):

This following link:

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

has the explanation you are looking for.

Comment: Links should go in comments, not answers. Answers should contain some context.

Comment: sure... but what if the link contain exact answer?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer :) I suggest you quote some part of the linked content.

Comment: another complaint is that http://c-faq.com/ contains more recent version of that nice faq.

Comment: yeah i saw that link but the old one had all in one place, so preferred to post it. And thanks for the 'how-to-answer'. That was helpful.

Comment: c-faq.com has "section-at-a-time" mode too: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr

Comment: That link is totally wrong (talks about a different problem... it's about the difference between `int *a` and `int a[]` even if both of them allow `a[x]`).