# how a linker resolves linkage?

Tags: c, linker, linkage

i have two translation units..

file1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
extern char a[90];

int main(int argc,char ** argv){


//printf("%s ",a);

strcat(a,"y Code");
printf("%s",a);
return 0;
}
```

file2.c

```
char a[4]={'Q','u','i','r'};
```

by compilation and linking of project give no error but when i exceute the program it gives segmentation fault error(in Debug mode).
i think that some how the linker resolves wrong link for identifier a in file1.c to definition a in file2.c, this happens when i also change the data type of a in file2.c(definition of a) how it is possible, what mechanism the linker uses to link identifiers in same or different translation units?

Comment: Linking is done on identifiers only (names), not types AFAIK in C.

Comment: You are concatenating `y Code` to `char a[4]`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a segmentation fault because you have defined `char a[4]` and you have `extern char a[90]`

You also need to enable warnings using `-Wall`, during linkage step compiler recognizes this variable, thus you get no error.

Answer (score 0):

You may declare the object of incomplete type as in `file1.c`

```
extern char a[];
```

and then define it with complete type in `file2.c`

```
char a[4]={'Q','u','i','r'};
```

It means that the same array object can have incomplete type initially, but acquire a complete type later on. This doesn't, of course, mean that you can declare a as an `int` and then define it as a `double`. The only type-related freedom you have here is, again, to complete an incomplete type. No more.

Courtesy: [Shouldn't declaration match its definition when array is involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887537/shouldnt-declaration-match-its-definition-when-array-is-involved)

However, you may want to refrain from concatenating to a `char` array of unknown length.